# Android playlist vlc player

Tags: java, android, android-intent, vlc

Воспроизвести несколько видео файлов (из интернета) в vlc player.
В mx player есть такое - video_list. Сам vlc так же поддерживает плейлисты из интернета.

Вопрос - как передать в vlc player несколько видео файлов под видом плейлиста??

Пытался сделать как в mx - бестолку.

```
ArrayList<Uri> uriList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<>();
...
intent.putExtra("video_list", uriList.toArray(new Uri[uriList.size()]));
intent.putExtra("video_list.name", nameList.toArray(new String[nameList.size()]));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В интентах такого не нашел, но можно решить проблему другим способом.

Создать временный файл [m3u](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U) и добавить в него нужные файлы

Пример:

```
#EXTM3U

/sdcard/video/file1.avi
/sdcard/video/file2.avi
/sdcard/video/file3.avi
```

Тип интента должен быть "video/*"

Если файл создаем в директории программы, куда нет прав vlc, то файл передавать нужно через FileProvider почитать можно [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32950381/3515000)